# ASP.NET RequiredFieldValidator error message is red only in IIS

Tags: asp.net, validation

I have a `RequiredFieldValidator`:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="nameValidator" ControlToValidate="name"
     runat="server" Display="Dynamic" Message="You must input a name"/>
```

My body's default font color is white. When I run my code in IIS, the error message properly has the following inline style applied:

```
<span style="display: inline; color: Red;">You must input a name</span>
```

However, if I run the same code in Visual Studio's built-in web server, it doesn't apply the `color: Red` style and the text shows up as white:

```
<span style="display: inline;">You must input a name</span>
```

Does anyone know why the style is properly being applied in IIS, but not in the VS web server?

Comment: This might help you - http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/638592/requiredfieldvalidator-loses-style-color-attribute

Comment: Are you running in different browsers for IIS/VS Webserver?

Comment: rs: Thanks, that was definitely the problem.

Answer (score 1):

set rendering compatability to 3.5 mode in Web.Config:

pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5"

Comment: thanks ! I had to add clientIdMode also. Here is the full tag

<pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5"  clientIDMode="AutoID"  >